# Why are es6-promise and zone.js not included in the angular 2 5min Typescript tutorial

Tags: angular

Have a look here:

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

```
<!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

I have checked other angular 2 tutorials which loaded those:

```
<script src="~/lib/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/es6-promise.js"></script>

<script src="~/lib/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/system.js"></script>

<script src="~/lib/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular2.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/zone.js"></script>
```

Additionally there arre the `es6-promise.js` and `zone.js`

Why would I need to include those libraries, when the 5 min tutorial works without them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this [overview](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/docs/bundles/overview.md#required-polyfills)

> Polyfills are required for Angular 2 to function properly (the exact
>   list depends on the browser used) and external dependencies (zone.js).
>   To ease setup of Angular 2 applications there is one file -
>   angular2-polyfills.js - that combines:
>
> a pollyfill mandatory for all browsers: reflect-metadata zone.js Note:
>   angular2-polyfills.js contains code that should be loaded into the
>   browser as the very first code of the web application even before the
>   module loader. The preferred solution is to load the mentioned file in
>   a script tag as early as possible.

Basically angular2-polyfills.js is a bundle for zone.js and reflect-metadata

and if you check the code, you can see es6-promise is there as well.

Comment: Thanks, then I will use that one polyfill!

Answer (score 0):

The bundled version of angular2 includes these dependencies. In your second example you are accessing the raw version, not the bundle, therefore you are adding the dependencies yourself.

Inconsistencies are probably due to different developers writing the tutorials. Perhaps each have their own opinion on how to load angular2 in development.